# In mvc3 how to access the div inner text of view in controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have one Div ,that is editable.when i edit the div after click one button how to access div  inner text in controller...In Controller Request[""]...is possible??

Comment: `div` is not an `input` element where users can "edit" it's content as you mention in your question. I suggest you edit your question, add some code you have and explain it. And then ask again specific issues in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand your question correctly, but if you are trying to process contents of a div in controller, ajax will be your best friend. You can use e.g. jQuery to load the changed div content and then make a post to your controller's action that will process it.

Comment: thanks bro....i had using ajax call ,and thats workd..i put the code below.. function getPerson(currentId, content) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Action name", "Controllername")',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',               
                cache: false,
                data: { id: currentId, data: content, pagename: "AboutUs" },
                success: function (person) {
                   $('#FirstName').val(person.FirstName);
                    $('#LastName').val(person.LastName);
                }
            });

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible as a `<div>` element is not an input element that has a value posted back to the server when a `<form>` element is submitted. You could

1. Use a `<textarea>` or `<input type="text"/>` instead of a `<div>`
2. Use JavaScript on the client side to get the innertext of the `<div>` and include the value in the values submitted to the server.

Personally, I'd go for option 1 and simply put a `<textarea>` inside of the "editable" `<div>`